# Dart, regular expression only allow #-_ *.?

Tags: regex, dart

I found out how to allow only alphabet and numbers

but I want to allow " # - * . _ " this five characters too (# - * . _)

so how to write down that only allows numbers  +lower case alphabet + # - * . _   ?  thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to allow only `#-*._`, just do

```dart
final RegExp regex = RegExp(r"^[#\-*._]+$");
print(regex.hasMatch("abc"));  // false
print(regex.hasMatch("###"));  // true
print(regex.hasMatch("a#*"));  // false
print(regex.hasMatch(".#*"));  // true
```

If you want to also allow numbers and the lowercase alphabet:

```dart
final RegExp regex = RegExp(r"^[a-z0-9#\-*._]+$");
```

Comment: hi I`m just testing but "(" is not filtering on this I guess when I put the "(" it returns true

Comment: You need to escape the `-` in the character range. The range `[#-*]` matches all characters between `#` and `*`, which have character codes U+0023 and U+002a. That includes `(` with character code U+0028. (Another alternative is to have the `-` as the last character of the character range.) You can also use `\d` instead of `0-9`.
I've update the post.